# SQL "login failed for user [username]" error for windows service, but SSMS login works

Tags: sql-server, authentication, windows-services

I'm writing a windows service that needs to connect to a SQL server to retrieve some information. However, the server doesn't allow me to connect: `login failed for user [domain/username]`. The strange part is that everything works totally fine from inside SSMS. I can log in, query the database, and everything works out perfectly. It's only through the windows service that it's throwing that error.

For reference, here's the connection string I'm using:

> Data Source=sqlserveraddresshere;Initial Catalog=databasenamehere;User ID=domain\username;Password=password`

I doubt that this is related, but when I try to use Integrated Security it's getting my computer name instead of my own user name. I'm 99% sure this is because our anti-virus and monitoring software is spoofing an administrator user on top of my windows session to do its job. In any case, just entering the correct username and password should be working regardless, right?

I took a look at some other questions involving the same error, but they were all unrelated. From what I can tell everyone who can get in through SSMS can access their SQL server through code, too. This is the most similar question I could find, although it didn't help much:
[Can't connect to SQL Server: "Login failed for user "."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217472/cant-connect-to-sql-server-login-failed-for-user)

Also, before you ask, I HAVE ALREADY CHECKED FOR TYPOS. Actually, I've even tried to use other user's accounts to make sure there wasn't something funky going on with my permissions. If you need me to post any code let me know. Thanks for your help!

UPDATE:

I changed the account for the service and switched back to `IntegratedSecurity = true`. It seems like something has changed, because now I'm receiving a slightly different error:

> Cannot open database "mydatabase" requested by the login. The login failed. >Login failed for user 'MYDOMAIN\myUserName'.

Comment: Can you please check the SQL event log (in Management Studio, expand server, expand Management, expand SQL Server Logs) and give us the full error for the failed login?  It should include an error number, severity and state.

Comment: Ah checking the SQL event log helped me learn something new: the server I'm trying to access is configured for Windows Authentication only. However, login  still fails when I use WA because it still sends my machine name rather than the account name. I'll do some more research to try and solve that issue now. 

Here's the error in full (with anonymized credentials): failed for user 'DOMAIN\MACHINE_NAME$'. Reason: Token-based server access validation failed with an infrastructure error. Check for previous errors. [CLIENT: 10.1.0.188]

Comment: Does the error have **Severity** and **State** values above the message you posted?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's working! Finally!

First, using Kevin's suggestion (comment underneath the original question), I checked through the SQL Server Logs (in Management Studio, expand server, expand `Management`, expand `SQL Server Logs`). This is how I found more lengthy error reporting that helped me diagnose the issue.

Turns out the server didn't allow anything other than Windows Authentication, so that's why my attempts at entering the UN/PW manually failed.

However, I still had the issue where the server was passing my machine name as the user instead of my username. This was fixed with [Duncan's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11198153/1294236) of changing the user that the service ran under to my name (right click in Services->Properties->Log On Tab).

Thanks to everyone for your help, much appreciated.

Comment: To add to VVander's answer, on the Log On tab, select "This Account" radio button and click browse. Type in "your name" and the system will do the AD search to authenticate the username. then type in your system password and apply. You should get a message something like "system accepts the username/password for this service.." . that's it. It will work.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check the user account that the service is running under. By the sounds of things it is running as `Local System` which will try and pass the machine name through as the login.

Try changing this to a least privileged domain user (or for testing, you could use your own account) and then granting that user a login to the SQL Server. That should do the trick.

Comment: Ok I changed the account for the service and switched back to IntegratedSecurity = true. It seems like something has changed, because now I'm receiving a slightly different error:

Cannot open database "mydatabase" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'MYDOMAIN\myUserName'.

I'll add this to the original question, too.

Comment: You probably need to create a database user for the login. Right click on the login in the Object Explorer in SSMS and check the User Mappings in the left hand pane. Alternatively you can run `CREATE USER [blah] FOR LOGIN [login]` against the database

Comment: In the end it turns out I entered the database name wrong and that's why your suggestion didn't work at first and gave me that error. This might help others though.

Answer (score 0):

What is the username you are passing to SQL Server to log in?  According to the connection string, it looks like you are using the literal "domain\username" as the user.  The password should be updated to be the correct password instead of the literal "password".

I got this error quite a bit when I started out programming in C# writing a database backed application.  I have a mixed mode environment for my application, and I pass the SQL Server username and password instead of what I use to log into my computer.  This is a security policy I like to enforce so that the database controls who can log in and what permissions they get.  Is that a fit for what you are trying to do?  If so, I may be able to offer better assistance, as well as more specific code, too.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make this clear in the original question. I changed the values in the connection string before posting it. In my program I'm actually using the username and password that should have access to the server.

Comment: When I get home tonight, I'll post my connection string that I use with my application.  It's set to use SQL Server authentication, but I presume it should serve as a starting model for any type of authentication.

Comment: Thanks, any help is appreciated. Although I have been using connectionstring.com's examples as well as using MS's ConnectionStringBuilder class in .NET, if your string is different it could help.

Comment: In my experience with connectionstring.com (which is a wonderful resource) they are extremely generic.  I should have something up here around 6:00 - 6:30 Central Time.  BTW, are you planning on using Windows authentication or SQL Server authentication?

Comment: I'm now using Windows Authentication since I found the server only accepts that. I finally figured everything out, so I don't need your help after all, but thank you anyway. If you're curious, I posted the solution as an answer.