# Windows Service SQL Server error - "Login failed for user"

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, service, windows-services

I have a Windows Service written in C# being run on a Windows Server 2012 R2 machine which connects to a remote SQL Server 2012 instance also on a Windows Server 2012 R2 Server.

The SQL Connection String is defined in the App Config as follows:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="destinationConnectionString" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
    connectionString="Server=10.42.42.10;Database=mydb;User ID=myuser;Password=mypass" />
</connectionStrings>
```

When running the service, the output error log shows:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user
>   'myuser'.
>
> Error Number:18456, State:1, Class:14

So I check the SQL Server Logs to find out more information about the error and find this

> Login failed for user myuser Reason: Password did not match for the
>   login provided"
>
> Source: Logon  Message: Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 8.

The problem is I know these credentials are correct. I've checked and double checked.

I am able to prove the credentials work by opening SQL Server Management Studio on the source machine, and connecting to the remote SQL Server using the exact same Server, User ID and Password with "SQL Server Authentication" authentication mode.

In fact I have 2 different users that I'm able to connect with using SSMS, but that fail using the Windows service. If I am able to connect to the remote machine using mixed mode auth directly in SSMS. Why not in my Windows service?

I'm at a loss here, could anyone suggest what the issue might be?

Edit: I can even successfully connect to the remote machine using the following command:

```
sqlcmd -S 10.42.42.10 -U myuser -P mypass -d mydb
```

Comment: Do you have the error state of the error (see [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2006/02/21/536201.aspx))?

Comment: If the user/password is correct and the config file has the same, then the service must be using a different connection string.

Comment: @adrianbanks I've added in the error state now. On the client machine it shows Error State 1, but on the SQL Server machine it shows "Error 18456, State 8"

Comment: State 8 is the correct one (the one shown in the server). This means "password mismatch", so it appears that you have the wrong password. Are you *sure* you are using the correct password?

Comment: Yes I'm sure. As I already mentioned in my original post, I am able to open SQL Server Management Studio on the source machine, and connecting to the remote SQL Server using the exact same Server, User ID and Password.

Comment: 7 months later, you have gone through all the typical troubleshooting methods for this problem? https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlsakthi/2011/02/06/troubleshoot-connectivitylogin-failures-18456-state-x-with-sql-server/ and https://kebi.academy/microsoft-sql-server-error-18456-login-failed-for-user

Comment: Hi Jeremy. Yes I have gone through those to the best I can see. Seeing as im using sql authentication, its my understanding most of the complexities around the windows authentication stuff in #3 of your first link doesn't apply.

Comment: I wonder if this is related to this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175475(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: Check this link for same issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197591/sql-login-failed-for-user-username-error-for-windows-service-but-ssms-login

Answer (score 3):

The proper syntax for specifying the initial database is:

*Server=10.42.42.10;**Initial Catalog**=mydb;User ID=myuser;Password=mypass*

My best guess is that it is ignoring the "Database" in your string and possibly trying to connect to the default database setting for the login (possibly master maybe?) and doesn't have at least public role to it.  Although I've found out that "Database" is a valid alternative.

It's possible there is a character in your password that is tripping it up.  Semicolons and equal signs will be particularly problematic.  Try putting double quotes around your User ID and Password like:

*Server=10.42.42.10;Initial Catalog=mydb;User ID="myuser";Password="mypass"*

If there's a quotation mark in your password you will have to replace it with two of them for each occurrence.

Once you get your connection string built, then you have to ensure that it will parse properly in XML.  Which means escaping control characters and the other special characters such as:

```
< with &lt;
> with &gt;
& with &amp;
' with &apos;
" with &quot;
```

If you open up your app config file in a browser it should show you if it looks proper.

I recommend adding the contents of your entire connection string to our output log of your service.  That way you can see what it looks like.  At the point before you attempt to open the connection, get it with:

```
string connStr = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("myConnectionString");
```

Then output the connStr value to the log.  It will show you what values are being used at least.

Comment: I found out Database is a valid alternative.  I added some more things to try to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You might use some special character in password, that is reserved for XML. If so, you'll need to use escape character as a replacement.

For instance, if your password is `PASS<WORD` the valid entry in config file would be: `PASS&lt;WORD`

Comment: Yeah, dot (.) is fine. I think we have run out of options here, so you must run standard troubleshooting here (password error might be misleading). Try this ones:
*Can you temporarily change password to see if new is working?
*Are you sure you are using right app.config? Some dev apps might have multiple ones in different catalogs, especially when app is multi layered.
Is your server open for SQL logins (SQL Server and Windows authentication mode)?
*Is your login turned on and have correct permissions?
*Can you try creating new user and test connection on it?
*Is your firewall turned on?

Answer (score 1):

I have used this [site](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlconnection/) to find the correct pattern

What you have is valid: 
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
Password=myPassword;

Are you trying to connect to an instanced sql server? *Server=10.42.42.10/SomeInstance*

Comment: Hi hivie7510. Nope I double checked and it's not an instanced server. I even tried connecting to 10.42.42.10/MSSQLSERVER out of desperation but no luck.

Comment: This is probably a dumb question, but was your sql server setup to allow windows and sql account or just windows?

Comment: It's mixed mode authentication (so both). Have been stung by that in the past, so I was sure to check that.

I'm able to connect using SSMS from a remote machine using the sql credentials too.

Comment: Sorry, but I am stumped.  Is there anything in your local event logs?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest adding the semicolon, `;`, after the password in the connection string.  Perhaps it's being parsed weirdly.

I also wonder whether: is a semicolon in your actual password?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're attempting a Windows account but there's also a SQL account named the same way. If so, make sure you prefix the Windows account with the domain name. E.g. you might have Windows account of `MYDOMAIN\sa` with `P@ssword`, whilst SQL server account is `sa` and its password is `P@ssw0rd`.

To make sure what accounts exists, log in the SQL server as an admin and check what accounts are listed under "Security" node of both the server itself and the database of interest.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and here is my solution:

I found out that I was using named instance of an SQL server and changed `Server` of my connection string from `Server=localhost` to `Server=localhost\SQLEXPRESS` and everything worked just fine for me! :)